¿NumPy 2.0 más lento que 1.26?
Tengo un script que calcula números primos con NumPy. No tengo problemas con eso. Al ejecutar el mismo código en Python 3.11.1 y NumPy 1.26 tarda 20 segundos aproximadamente y en Python 3.12 y NumPy 2.0 el tiempo sube casi a 40 segundos.
import numpy as np
import time

print(np.__version__)
startcount=2
endcount=2_000_000

timestart=time.time()

array1=np.arange(startcount,(endcount+1))
array2=np.zeros((endcount//10),dtype=int)
array2indice=0
i=2
while i<(endcount+1) and array1.size>1:
   # print(i)
    array3=np.array(array1%i>0)
    array1=array1[array3]
    #print(array1)
    i=array1[0]
    array2[array2indice]=i
    array2indice+=1
    #print(array1.size)

timeend=time.time()
print("el tiempo de ejecucion es ", timeend-timestart)
print(array2)


Estoy aprendiendo pero no tengo problemas con el código. Mi duda es por qué tarda mucho más?

Posiblemente. Este tipo de preguntas no tienen una respuesta adecuada. Lo único que puedes hacer es un benchmark adecuadamente. Puedes usar timeit para eso. Algunas opciones son estas.

saludos. ya he encontrado una respuesta la pondré como respuesta continuación como respuesta gracias por tomarse el tiempo de aportar a mi pregunta

Result alguien me aporto que revisara los tipos de dato y en efecto. el tipo de dato default para un array de numpy cambio de 32 a 64 en la versión 2.0 esto ocasiona que aumente mucho el tiempo de ejecución. esto se puede solucionar fácilmente especificando el dtype=np.int32 en la declaración de los array , con esto el rendimiento vuelve a ser el mismo
espero que esto ayude a alguien que llegue aquí en el futuro

Si el problema es el tipo de dato, posiblemente tenga relación con el tamaño del array ya que si el rendimiento de un cálculo es el mismo para números de 32 y 64 bits en un procesador de 64 bits. Básicamente los números de 64 bits ocupan el doble de memoria que los de 32 y es más probable que no entre bien en memoria caché, haciendo que tarde más tiempo. Si tu arreglo fuese pequeño, seguro no verías ninguna diferencia de rendimiento.

Coincido totalmente con la observación de Mateo y una aclaración, Numpy siempre ha heredado los tipos por defecto del compilador de C de turno (long int en este caso), siempre ha usado enteros de 64-bits por defecto en Linux y OSX de 64 bits, pero creo que en Windows esto no era así y en la versión 2 lo han cambiado para que dejara de ser el bicho raro...

Muchas gracias por tomar el tiempo de aportar a mi consulta. Investigare más sobre los temas que mencionan
